# How to call particular class value in html using response.css in python scraping while there is same classnames

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a string from HTMLpage using python scrapy respponse.css, Here the values are in different calses and populating in single string but my code resulting different output except what i need

HTML page is like below:

```
<div class="a-row a-size-small a-color-secondary">  
  <span data-component-type="s-coupon-component" data-component-props="{&quot;asin&quot;:&quot;B07NNNVMVV&quot;}" 
    class="rush-component" data-component-id="19">
    <span class="s-coupon-clipped aok-hidden">
        <span class="a-color-base">$0.61 coupon applied.</span>
    </span>
    <span class="s-coupon-unclipped">
      <span class="a-size-base s-coupon-highlight-color s-highlighted-text-padding aok-inline-block">
        Save $0.61
      </span> 
      <span class="a-color-base"> with coupon</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

my python code to extract value:
info = amzscrape.css(".a-row.a-size-small.a-color-secondary span").css('::text').extract()

Expected Output: Save $0.61 with coupon

But Actual Result from above code:

'\n'
                     '     \n'
                     '         $0.61 coupon applied. \n'
                     '     \n'
                     '     \n'
                     '        \n'
                     '\n'
                     '\n'
                     ' \n'
                     '    Save $0.61\n'
                     ' \n'
                     '\n'
                     '          with coupon \n'
                     '     \n'
                     '    \n'
                     ' \n'
                     '         $0.61 coupon applied. \n'
                     '     $0.61 coupon applied. \n'
                     '        \n'
                     '\n'
                     '\n'
                     ' \n'
                     '    Save $0.61\n'
                     ' \n'
                     '\n'
                     '          with coupon \n'
                     '     \n'
                     '    Save $0.61\n'
                     '  with coupon',

Comment: you supposed to point to the class with `s-coupon-unclipped` not it's parent

Comment: print("Savings info======",amzscrape.css(".a-row.a-size-small.a-color-secondary span.s-coupon-unclipped").css("::text").extract(),"******"*50)

output:
Savings info====== ['\n        \n\n\n', '\n    Save $2.94\n', '\n\n        ', ' with coupon', '\n    '] ****

Comment: how can i remove \n here?

Comment: `import re;`
`data = re.sub('\s+',' ', amzscrape.css(".a-row.a-size-small.a-color-secondary span.s-coupon-unclipped").css("::text").extract() ).strip()`

Comment: i am using atom here.. i think do i need to install re library? Is there anyother way to remove white space and \n with out this?

Comment: Atom is just a editor. you can install library from terminal. its simple. 
`pip3 install re`

Comment: And i suggest you to use xpath selector... which is more powerfull than css selector. Here is the great resource. https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 0):

```
#Import re
import re

#You will store data in a list
dataList = amzscrape.css(".a-row.a-size-small.a-color-secondary span.s-coupon-unclipped").css("::text").extract()

#output: >>> print(data)
#['\n      ', '\n        Save $0.61\n      ', ' \n      ', ' with coupon', '\n  ']

#Cleanse the each element of list and replace with single space
couponDataList=[]
for some_data in dataList:
    couponDataList.append(re.sub('\s+',' ',some_data).strip())

#if null or junk just discards.
coupon_list = list(filter(None, couponDataList))

#Output >>> print(coupon_list)
#['Save $0.61', 'with coupon']

#Join the list by single space
coupon_info = " ".join(coupon_list)

# Final out put >>> print(coupon_info)
#Save $0.61 with coupon
```